# Setting active docker machine in R

Tags: r, docker, docker-machine

I wanted to do some webscraping in more professional way. To do this I wanted to start a docker machine and run selenium server on it from R.

My code:

```
shell("docker-machine create m1") # Creating docker machine (It is also visible in CMD manualy)

conf <- shell("docker-machine env m1", intern = T) # Geting the comands to set the machine "m1" active
conf <- conf[grepl("SET",conf)] # There was some REM functions so I removed it
for(i in 1:length(conf)){
  shell(conf[i]) # Activating each line of code separetly (They are only SET functions)
}

shell('docker-machine active')
```

The problem is that the last comannd gives me that there isn't any activated machine....

I have inputed every comannds of **docker-machine env m1** also manualy in CMD, then in CMD there was an active machine but in R wasn't.

Comment: Hi Kamil, can you share additional information to recreate the issue? e.g. Dockerfile, how you start / build / run, any dependencies that are required. Best case I can recreate the issue on my machine and debug there.

Comment: Hi Clemens, I have only download and installed Docker Toolbox for Windows. Then I was trying my best to understand how the Docker works

Comment: Please share your error log

Comment: Why do you want to use docker machine and not docker desktop for windows? Additionally, why do you want to write that in R, and not in bash or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
```